# ANGULAR.js passing function from one component to another

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am trying to build a pokedex project with angular 12.

I want to pass a openDialog() function in my pokemon-list.component.html

but openDialog() is defined in a separate component called Dialog.
I've attached the project structure below.

[image: Project structure]

This is the error I get:
(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: openDialog is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)

this is what i have done :
in my html document of list component

```
<button id="button" onclick="openDialog()">More Stats</button>
```

and in dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class dialogComponent {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  public openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(dialogComponent);
    
  }
}
```

my final goal is to show a dialog after clicking the button

Comment: Angular doesn't recognize `onclick` event. It must be `(click)`. Try: `<button id="button" (click)="openDialog()">More Stats</button>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is in `pokemon-list.component.html` :

```
<button id="button" (click)="openDialog()">More Stats</button>
```

then, I think this function:

```
public openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(dialogComponent);
}
```

Should be in the `pokemon-list.component.ts`. That way, when the button is clicked, the `openDialog` function will be called and open the `dialogComponent`.

Comment: Happy to hear it :)